Как поменять название столбцов в dataframe
Есть dataframe post_count мне нужно вывести у каких пользователей сколько постов в формате: %UserID% - %Количество постов%; Но почему-то у получившейся таблицы я не могу переименовать столбцы ни методом rename ни методом columns
import pandas
import requests

info = requests.get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts")

info_table = pandas.DataFrame(info.json())
post_count = info_table['userId'].value_counts()


во-первых, value_counts() возвращает Series, а не DataFrame, поэтому вы не можете переименовать там "столбцы".
во-вторых, вам нужно не value_counts(), а группировка с подсчетом:
post_count = info_table.groupby('userId', as_index=False)['title'].count().rename(columns={"title": "Количество постов"})

post_count:
   userId  Количество постов
0       1                 10
1       2                 10
2       3                 10
3       4                 10
4       5                 10
5       6                 10
6       7                 10
7       8                 10
8       9                 10
9      10                 10


value_counts() в данном случае дает тот же результат, что и groupby('userId').count()

@АлексейР ну и хорошо.

Метод .rename() на Series работает немного по-другому, чем на DF, но работает. К вашему решению нужно просто добавить еще два метода - Series.rename() и Series.reset_index(). Первый, чтобы переименовать серию, а второй чтобы преобразовать серию во фрейм, одновременно перенеся индекс в столбец userId и название серии в заголовок столбца Количество постов.
post_count = info_table['userId'].value_counts().rename("Количество постов").reset_index()

   userId  Количество постов
0       1                 10
1       2                 10
2       3                 10
3       4                 10
4       5                 10
5       6                 10
6       7                 10
7       8                 10
8       9                 10
9      10                 10


Более короткий способ получить тоже самое. Без rename и без использования requests:
import pandas as pd

df = (pd
    .read_json("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts")
    .value_counts('userId')
    .to_frame("Количество постов")
    .reset_index())

